# Why is there a key lookup even though I have non clustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am facing an issue where key lookup is shown in query plan even though I have created indexes on `IsGrantor` and `IsGrantee`. Please see the attached screenshot and output list.

[image]

[image]

The table roughly contains about 0.5 million records.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What columns do `IsGrantor` and `IsGrantee` actually index? Detail on the actual relationship & index structure would be useful. Do they include the actual foreign keys of the relationship, or just boolean flags? If only booleans, the DB may not consider them very "selective".

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: @Thomas W: You are right. It is simply boolean flags.

Comment: You can try to create an index out of those 2 flags and the column you're using for the join (if there's a join).

Comment: @Szymon: I have already created index on those 2 column (which is my question). The join column is DocumentNameID and it is clustered index.

Comment: So can you add DocumentNameID to the index? It's hard to say though without seeing the query.

Comment: @Szymon: DocumentNameID  is already a clustered index since it is primary key. In Sql server, clustered indexes are automatically a part of non-clustered index as far as I know. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @JoelWilson I think they're not really. Every index is used separately when executing queries.

Comment: @Szymon: Please read this link: http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/query-performance-tuning and specifically this: **technically speaking the clustering key doesn't need to be an included column.**

Comment: That's about `INCLUDE` which just means that the clustering key is always in the output of the index (otherwise there would be no way to look up the record from an index). But not in the ordering used by the index.

Answer (score 0):

Key lookup will happen if your index is not a covering index. By non covering it means that it can't provide all columns required by the query. So to get the remaining column key lookup on the cluster index is done.

```
You can try following
  Drop unnecessary columns from select list
  Include columns in your non cluster index to make it covering.
```

Also if you reduce the number of rows in the result set then a few key lookups will not hurt much.

Comment: I think having just the boolean flags in the index is not very useful -- you've got 0.5 million records, so an index with one boolean still leaves 0.25 million records to scan. Very inefficient. The engine would far prefer an index with high selectivity which _covers the columns it needs_ for the query plan.

Comment: Agree with Thomas. One use case of index on boolean columns is when either true/false is very less in number. In that case a filtered index can be tried.

Comment: Sometimes TOP can trigger a key lookup as well.  I had a query that returned 20 rows go from .1 seconds to well over 100 seconds just because I added a TOP 50.  This caused all the nonclustered index seeks to change over to one key lookup, which ended up scanning the ENTIRE table.  BTW, none of the nonclustered indexes were covering, but why should they be?  SQL should know if it's scanning an entire table and avoid that at all costs.  I believe this is a bug in the optimizer, as I can reproduce it on demand.